# GraphQL, Apollo, Relay … how do they fit together?

Tags: graphql

When trying to get started with GraphQL, you meet a lot of new terms: Some are related to the concept of GraphQL itself (mutations, subscriptions, …), but there is also an entire ecosystem around it, which – unfortunately – is not always separated clearly from GraphQL itself. However, I find it quite hard to tell where one thing ends, and where the other one starts, and what the differences are, and what is needed when.

So, to name a few of these terms:

- GraphQL
- Apollo
- Apollo Client
- Relay

Can you explain maybe in a few sentences what these things (except GraphQL) are, what they are good for, and how they relate to each other (or don't)? And, which important tools / concepts are missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### GraphQL The language

GraphQL is a query language. It has a [specification](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/) that defines the language, schemas and also the execution of GraphQL queries. Learning these things is a great place to start and completely programming language agnostic.

#### GraphQL implementations

Then there are different GraphQL implementations in different languages that allow you to create a schema and describe how the query resolves to values. Usually these implementations validate the query against the schema that you have defined and take over the execution. Pretty much all of the JavaScript ecosystem uses [GraphQL.js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/) but there are [many more implementations in other languages](https://graphql.github.io/code/).

#### GraphQL Servers

GraphQL is also transport layer agnostic. That means that usually the GraphQL implementations don't come with an HTTP server. But often we use HTTP to make GraphQL queries, this is why there are some libraries that use these implementations and provide an easy way to create an HTTP server on top (e.g. by providing a middleware for an HTTP framework or coming with a whole server). I think in JavaScript pretty much everyone uses [Apollo Server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/) because it brings some more features and it integrates smothly with the Apollo ecosystem and the services offered by Apollo the company.

Apollo Server has also very much popularized the *SDL* (Schema Definition Language) approach of defining a GraphQL API. With the SDL approach the GraphQL schema is not created using code but by defining the Schema in a special language (also part of the GraphQL spec) and defining single resolver function seperately from that definition. This get's you started quickly but my feeling is that it is not very popular for large APIs. But you can simply pass your GraphQL.js schema to Apollo Server.

#### GraphQL Clients

When we have a server running we can make queries to the server using a simple HTTP client like the `fetch` function of the browser. That works pretty well but the power of GraphQL really shines when we use a client that supports caching an automatic query fetching when they are needed. This way we can reach the promised land of declarative data fetching / data dependencies. Facebook has published their own client library that is designed for the unique requirements of a large web enterprise. The library is called [Relay](https://github.com/facebook/relay) and the newer version (breaking from the older version) is usually reffered to as *Relay Modern*. But Relay is relatively complicated and needs a specific build chain so that GraphQL became really interesting when Apollo released a lighweight client alternative known as [Apollo Client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client). Apollo Client developed a lot over the years and now supports a lot of configuration. Also `apollo-react` allows to use Apollo Client with React whereas Relay is specifically built for React. With Apollo gaining quite some weight over the years the folks at Formidable Labs have created [Urql](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql).

#### Conclusion

You can use all of these technologies together. Many people simply chose to use the Apollo Ecosystem together, which is probably a solid choice. If you have used Redux before you will probably feel at home using Apollo Client or Urql. If you are building a large app with a performance focus you should consider Relay and understand what contrains this puts on the way you build the GraphQL schema.